# how I can translate an object in angular using @ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have an object in two languages: Spanish and English I can translate the object 1 time, by default it is in English, I can traslate to Spanish from English but later I can not translate again in English etc....

room.component.html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav  navbar-right">
                <span class="form-inline">
                    <select 
                        class="form-control" 
                        #selectedLang 
                        (change)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
                      <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" 
                        [value]="language"
                        [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
                        {{ language }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </span>

            </ul>

      <div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>     <h4>{{ room.titleEs }}</h4></ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock> <h4>{{ room.title }}</h4></ng-template>
```

room.component.ts

```
 switchLang(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
   // this.cdRef.markForCheck();
  //  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    if(this.translate.use('en'))
    {
      this.translateEn = true;
    }
    else if(this.translate.use('es'))
    {
      this.translateEn = false;
    }

 translate.addLangs(['en', 'es']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

  public translateEn:boolean;
```

I have to detect the change in the select {{ language }} I tried with onChanges but doesnt works and aswell with ChangeDetectorRef....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `switchLang` function, which checks the selected language not probably using the `this.translate.use` function.

`this.translate.use` is used to change the language, not to check which one is selected, and anyway it returns an observable not a boolean.

So if you want to check it correctly, you have to use `this.translate.currentLang` or just the `language` parameter in your case.

Try the following:

```js
switchLang(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
    this.translateEn = language === 'en';
}
```

**Note:** There is no need to use two keys one for each language, you can only use the same key in two language translation files, then use the `translate` pipe to get the proper value based on the `currentLang`.